# Linux kernel sleeping in driver read function

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm developing Linux kernel character driver and in read function I sleep in a loop until I get a data from the hardware. If I kill an user application while it is blocked in read syscall, the application is still working before I return from read syscall. Is there a possibility to determinate in the driver that the application is terminated, so I can return from the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are waiting for the data you should add your process to waiting queue (add_wait_queue()) then use set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE) and invoke schedule(). When the data comes in - it should be somehow recognized - for example using some interrupt and then wake up the sleeping task (wake_up()). There are plenty examples in kernel sources.

In other words - in read function you need to go to sleep when there is no data and in some other path (interrupt) you need to wake up this read function. Better don't do the busy waiting in read function.